# why svn doesn't allow tag with subdirectories?

Tags: svn, tags, subdirectory

in **svn 1.6**, when I try to create a tag based on a particular revision number, tortoise fails because of a path failure.

e.g.: `${svn_url}/tags/` is empty, no prior tags created.

I want to create a like this: `${svn_url}/tags/MyProject/R1.0`

svn returns the error msg: `Error: '.../tags/MyProject/R1.0' path not found`

now, if I first create a tag at `MyProject` level and then another one on `MyProject/R1.0` that works. But I then need to clean up the tagged files when I created a tag with `MyProject`.

Is this a known unsupported command or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Subversion tags are directory conventionally placed in the `tags` directory right beneath your project's repository root directory. For this reason you need to create all the elements of your tag path. assuming `${svn_url}/tags` exists in your repository:

```
svn mkdir ${svn_url}/tags/MyProject -m "MyProject directory"
svn copy ${svn_url}/trunk/MyProject ${svn_url}/tags/MyProject/R1.0 -m"R1.0 branch"
```